# How to generate .cab File

Tags: c#, cab

I want to generate a `.cab` File

How can I do it?

I am developing in C# (visual studio 2008, .NET Framework 3.5)
I can ganerate the `.exe` file, but how can I generate the `.cab`?

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you are trying to achieve. Building a cab file on it#s own is not very useful and there is better solutions for most of the cases where it would be.

Comment: Easiest thing to do these days is to shell it out to `iexpress.exe`.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?? you can Deploy CAB Files Using ClickOnce Deployment

Comment: Call [makecab](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875545(v=ws.10).aspx) via MSBuild (if part of build) or `Process.Start` if it is from your code.

Comment: I have already my app but I want to install it on a barcode reader.
I Can't put a `.exe` file there. I need a `.cab`


How Can I do it? 

I read [it][1]            [1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b8fd8ss(v=vs.80).aspx but I don't understand so much

Comment: @vcsjones I did it! Thank You so much! You Rule! [look it] (http://yolosolucionoasi.blogspot.mx/2010/04/crearmodificar-archivo-cab.html)

Comment: I followed the steps [here](http://yolosolucionoasi.blogspot.mx/2010/04/crearmodificar-archivo-cab.html)
It really helps. It's very useful

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has example C++ code to generate a .CAB file at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797926(v=vs.85).aspx. This sample uses Win32 Cabinet API functions (FCICreate, FCIAddFile, etc)...you can P/Invoke from C# to call these same APIs.